# Maven dependency in zip format with classifier

Tags: maven, zip, dependency-management

I am trying to import some schemas from a project which are in zip format. The name of the file is `mySchema-1.0.32-schema.zip`. My dependency looks like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>mySchema</artifactId>
    <version>${schema.version}</version>
    <classifier>schema</classifier>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

But the dependency does not get imported. It is in my repo (I have checked), and I have the source dependency for the same project and it works just fine. Are my classifier and my type right? Is this the way to import a `zip` file?

**EDIT:**

I've found out that if I change the `<classifier>` to `source` it does import the sources, and if I change it to `-schemas` it spits out an error. Hence, the import seems to be working. And although I can't see it in my list of dependencies in IntelliJ IDEA, if I run `mvn dependency:tree`, it exists there:
`\- some.group.id:mySchema:zip:schema:1.0.32-SNAPSHOT:compile`

It might be my unzipping that is not working:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>unpack</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>unpack</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
          <artifactItem>
            <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>mySchema</artifactId>
            <version>${schema.version}</version>
            <classifier>schema</classifier>
            <type>zip</type>
            <overWrite>false</overWrite>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/json</outputDirectory>
          </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

And just to clarify, my output directory exists.

Comment: That looks correct to me, as long as `${schema.version}` is actually defined.  Is the dependency in a `<dependencies>` block or `<dependencyManagement>`?

Comment: `${schema.version}` is defined and works fine, as I use it in another dependency. It is in the `<dependencies>` block. Should it be in `<dependencyManagement>`?

Comment: After `mvn clean compile`, are these files effectively in `src/main/resources/json` or there is nothing there?

Comment: No, it should be in `<dependencies>`.  Thanks for double checking. Is there a reason the resources are copied to `/src/main/resources` instead of `${project.build.directory}/classes` (for example)? Could the plugin executions be happening in the wrong order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Added this plugin under the `<build>` section:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>unpack-config</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals><goal>unpack-dependencies</goal></goals>
        <configuration>
          <includeGroupIds>some.group.id</includeGroupIds>
          <includeArtifactIds>mySchema</includeArtifactIds>
          <includeClassifiers>schema</includeClassifiers>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <additionalClasspathElements>
        <additionalClasspathElement>${project.build.directory}</additionalClasspathElement>
      </additionalClasspathElements>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```